# Div se movendo na mudança de tela

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

meu site inicial possui de inicio um html:

```
<header class="headd">
    <div id="divcentral">
        <a href="index.html" id="linklogocentral"><img src="img/logo.png" id="logocentral"></a>
        <h1 id="titulo">Lukas Monteiro</h1>
        <h2 id="subtitulo">Bem vindo</h2>
        <a href="#meuMenu" id="linksetabaixo" class="scroll"><img src="botao/setabaixo.png" id="setabaixo"></a>
    </div>
</header>
```

e no css coloquei:

```
header {
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;  
background-image: url(../img/backgroundheader1.png); 
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
}

#divcentral {
width: 407px;
height: 500px;
margin: auto;
padding-top: 200px;
text-align: center;
}
```

para que a parte inicial do site ocupe 100% em qualquer tamanho de tela. Porém, quando eu **expando a tela**(aumento a tela que estou) a **div central** sobe um pouco, desalinhando o que é pra ficar no meio.

Foto na tela minimizada
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foto na tela maximizada
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para deixar a div exatamente no meio em qualquer tamanho de tela? ainda nao consigo fazer isso.
Quando faço um site no meu notebook, e abro num computador TUDO fica fora de lugar (geralmente é em altura) já que nas laterais eu sempre centralizo ou coloco margin left em %.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o recente e moderno `display: flex` para solucionar os seus problemas!

```css
#container{
    background-color: steelblue;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}


#center{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="center">
  </div>
</div>
```

No seu caso, você poderá definir na "div pai" da sua imagem o valor `display:flex`, combinado com `justify-content: center` e `align-items: center` para centralizar o "elemento filho" (que seria sua imagem)

Comment: sem querer abusar da sua boa vontade, poderia me explicar o que o display flex & o justify-content fazem?

Comment: ah, e obrigado. 
segui o que vc falou e alinhou certinho!

Comment: Talvez isso te ajude, https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/CSS/Usando_caixas_flexiveis_css

Comment: @LukasMonteiro que bom, cara! boa sorte aí no seu projeto. Considere votar positivo e marcar a pergunta, caso isso tenha resolvido seu problema.